# Use single custom domain + URL for all firebase function calls

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'd like any https request to `MY_CUSTOM_DOMAIN/functions/**` to go to firebase functions.

I'm aware of the below solution:

[Use custom domain for firebase function http calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49825799/use-custom-domain-for-firebase-function-http-calls)
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#create_an_http_function_to_your_hosting_site

My understanding is this requires adding every single function to this list though. It would make my `firebase.json` file pretty long and probably I'll forget to update it on future functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites) to  use the wildcards and avoid repeating URL paths. Seems like you have to mention every function you are using for routing.

There is one workaround, As you are concerned about `firebase.json`. You can define an `index` function which determines the specific path by using [`req.path`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs/issues/23#issuecomment-510704908)  and calls other Cloud Functions to handle the respective request.

Also have a look at this [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50071454/18265570) & [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55681939/18265570)